# Add custom groups to custom ribbon tab from different features

Tags: development, ribbon

I have two features in SharePoint 2010 project. Every feature has its own button that have to be placed in different groups on the same custom tab.

For example:

Feature1 adds "Hello" group  with "Say Hello" button to tab "My Custom Tab"

Feature2 adds "Bye" group with "Say Good Bye" button to tab "My Custom Tab"

I've tried to create empty tab and to use its Groups id for location attribute in CommandUIDefinition for group like this:

```
<CommandUIDefinition
            Location="MyCustomTag.Groups._children">
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial to create ribbon customizations (Buttons, Groups, etc.) and worked pretty well.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

Ribbon is very tricky, so I would create a very clean scaffolding project and test the tutorial code until the button appears as you like, and then migrate the working xml to your main project.